# CakePHP Session variable use in view page?

Tags: php, session, cakephp

I have a variable contaning "username" and want to get these values via session to any of the view pages.

How can I get this session variable in the view ?

Comment: For a CakePHP 3.x solution refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/32668870

Answer (score 12):

There's a [SessionComponent](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/sessions.html) available in your Controller that you can use like `$this->Session->write('Name', 'Value');`. Analogously there's also the [SessionHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/session.html) for the View, which does very similar things and can be used like `$session->read('Name');`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `$this->Session->read('myParam')` in your Views files.
But you can't use `$this->Session->write('myParam')`.

As noted [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/session.html):

> The major difference between the Session Helper and the Session
>   Component is that the helper does not have the ability to write to the
>   session.

Answer (score 2):

To use it in a helper you must remember to include it in your $helpers declaration:

```
class Foo extends AppHelper
{
    var $helpers = array('Session','Bar');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're in the controller, use the Session component.  It's included, by default, in all the controllers.  It has the Session::read() and Session::write() methods.  Check out http://book.cakephp.org/view/173/Sessions for more information.

I believe, if the Session component is like some of the other components, you can use it inside the views.  Try just doing $session->read() in your view code blocks.  If that doesn't work, try doing a $this->Session->read(...).  As a last resort, if none of those work, you can always use the good old PHP $_SESSION, although it's kinda veering outside the Cake framework.  However, if you are sure you're not going to use Cake's Session management (and you don't really have to, IMO, as it's little more than a wrapper around $_SESSION), then just know when to properly apply the hack.

Comment: The Cake Session management *is* more than just a wrapper around `$_SESSION`, as it supports several more backends for storing session data. You can choose to write the session to a database to potentially share it across servers without having to change a single instance of `$this->Session->write()` in your app.

Comment: True, although I think I would use a different method within php to change the other session handlers, rather than putting it inside Cake.  Guess you caught me thinking mostly of how I think of the component, for how I would use it.

Comment: @TravisLeleu Components are never made available in Views by Cake. I tested your beliefs and I'm pretty sure about that.

Answer (score -1):

User this in you App controller's before filter

> $this->Session->write('Person.eyeColor', 'username'); $green =
>   $this->Session->read('Person.eyeColor');
>   $this->set('username',$green);

This will give you result as you want

Answer (score -2):

You can pass the Session object from controller  to a view template using

```
$this->set('session',$this->Session);
```

Then in view file
use `$session->read('SessionName');`