# cakephp3 session deprecated

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cakephp-3.1

I have update into my project the last version of cakephp core.
Now I get this error:

```
Deprecated (16384): SessionHelper has been deprecated. Use request->session() instead. [CORE/src/View/Helper/sessionHelper.php, line 39]
```

The error I think is in this line:

```
if ($this->session->read('admin_logged_in')){
```

What should I use instead?

Thanks

Comment: Don't want to be a smart ass, but the error message tells you, doesn't it? "_... Use `request->session()` instead ..._"

Comment: The message tells you! “Use request->session() instead.”

Comment: I have used $this->request->session->read but return me errors:  Call to a member function read() on a non-object  @ndm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if ($this->request->session->read('admin_logged_in')){
```

should be fine.

**UPDATE**

As per the comment of @raph below the correct answer is

```
$this->request->session()->read('admin_logged_in')
```

Note the () after session

Comment: It returns error:  Call to a member function read() on a non-object

Comment: Where do you call it? In controller?

Comment: if ($this->request->session()->read('admin_logged_in')){ - "session()" is a method, not a property - my mistake :)

Comment: ... But, in 3.6, show this message: *Deprecated (16384): ServerRequest::session() is deprecated. Use getSession() instead. The setter part will be removed.*...

Update to: 
`$this->request->getSession()->read('admin_logged_in')`

Comment: Above answer is correct for cakephp 3.6 and prior. In Cakephp 3.7, session() changes to getSession

Answer (score 1):

In Cakehp 3.7, use getSession() instead.

```
$this->request->getSession()->read('admin_logged_in');
```

Ref: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html